# Example of invariance of Wald Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

In order to make us understand that the Wald doesn't work with a transformation of your parameter at H0, we have to test the following $H_0$'s:

A) $H_0: exp( \mu)=0.62$

B) $H_0:  \mu=ln(0.62)$

I can write the Wald test statistic for case B, which is

$W_B= (\mu - ln(0.62))^2 / Var( \mu)$ which matches the result we get out of Stata,

But what is the formula for $W_A$?

I think you have to apply the delta method, but I can't figure it out unfortunately. Thank you in advance!

Comment: On rereading your question I wonder: by $exp(\mu)$ do you mean $e^{\mu}$ (i.e. something like $e$ to the power of the mean of your data), or do you mean something like E$(\mu)$ (i.e. the expected value of your data)? I will alter my answer if the second.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you face is that $\sigma^{2}_{g(\mu)} \ne g(\sigma^{2}_{\mu})$, that is, the variance of a function of a variable, is not the same thing as the same function of the variance of the variable.

The Delta function (Oehlert, 1992) gives us a way to approximate the variance of the function of a variable. When applying the delta function there is a trade-off between complexity (corresponding to the order of a Taylor series expansion entailed in the application) and accuracy of the approximation. However, the *first order* application of the delta method is often considered acceptable.

In general, the first order approximation looks like $g\left(X\right) \approx g\left(\mu\right) + g'\left(\mu\right)\left(X-\mu\right)$.

For the variance of a function, $g(\cdot)$, of the data, $X$ with $E(X)=\mu$, this translates into $\sigma^{2}_{g\left(X\right)} = \left[g'\left(\mu\right)\right]^{2}\sigma^{2}_{X}$.

If $g(X) = e^{X}$, then $\sigma^{2}_{e^{X}} = \sigma^{2}_{X}e^{2X}$.

So I think the Wald $\chi^{2} = \frac{e^{2X}}{\sigma^{2}_{X}e^{2X}}$, and the Wald $t = \frac{e^{X}}{\sqrt{\sigma^{2}_{X}e^{2X}}}$.

**References**

Oehlert, G. W. (1992). [A note on the delta method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2684406.pdf). *The American Statistician*, 46(1):27–29.

Comment: Hey I am very confused. Can you maybe clearly say what you mean with X and with $\mu$? Is $\mu$ the result we get out of our maximum likelihood, and X the $H_0$ test statistic?

Comment: Here $X$ is a quantity of interest (you did not define… presumably something like the mean of your data), and $\mu$ is the mean of $X$ (the first moment).

Comment: thank you for your help so far, in a separate answer I have given the approach as I understood it, I hope this is correct now...

Answer (score 2):

This is how I understood it:

We test the hypothesis that $exp(\theta_0) = exp(\hat{\theta})$. As we are applying a function to our variable, we have to use the delta method to calculate the variance: $\sigma_{g(\hat{\theta})}^2={[g'(\hat{\theta})]}^2\sigma_{\hat{\theta}}$, which is in our case equal to $\sigma_{\hat{\theta}}^{2} exp(2\hat{\theta})$ and hence our test statistic is equal to $\frac{{[g(\hat{\theta})-g(\theta_0)]}^2}{\sigma_{g(\hat{\theta})}^2}=\frac{{[exp(\hat{\theta})-exp(\theta_0)]}^2}{\sigma_{\hat{\theta}}^{2}exp(2\hat{\theta})}$ which is chi-squared distributed with one degree of freedom.

Unfortunately the calculation of this test statistic is not yet identical as the one of the stata output, so maybe I am still doing something wrong...